# Pointer to Array of Strings as CONST?

Tags: c

i program a application with mikroC PRO for AVR on the Hardware mikromedia for XMEGA.
I have different languages to show on a TFT Display.
I must switch the languages at runtime.

This works the following way, as example for the languages german and english.

I have two Pointer Arrays for the languages:

```
char* deu_hilfe[] = {
            "START = Startet die Messung",
            "STOPP = Stoppt die Messung",
            "SETUP = Aufruf des Setups",
            };

char *eng_hilfe[] = {
            "START = Start the measurement",
            "STOPP = Stop the measurment",
            "SETUP = Open the setup",
            };
```

I define a pointer to a pointer:

```
char **sprache_hilfe;
```

Then i allocate the pointer to the german or english array:

```
sprache_hilfe   = eng_hilfe;
sprache_hilfe   = deu_hilfe;
```

And use it:

```
TEXT_HI_HITXT_1.Caption  = sprache_hilfe[SP_HILFE_ALG_BUTTON];
```

This works fine, but my problem is, that the arrays are in the RAM and my RAM is full now.
So i tried to make the arrays CONST. 
But when i cast my array to the pointer with:

```
char **sprache_hilfe   = (char*)eng_hilfe;
```

I see no text on the display.
I think something is wrong with my cast.
Has anyone a better solution or knows what is wrong with my code?

Greetings from Germany
Patrick

Comment: There is no `const` in your declaration. Can you explain how you tried to make the arrays const? Anyway, casting `char **` to `char *` is never going to work.

Comment: BTW you probably should declare your arrays as `char const *const deu_hilfe[] = {` ..., then the compiler can put all of it into read-only area.

Comment: Your cast from a `char*` to `char**` shouldn't work. Could you check what you're really doing?

Comment: @MattMcNabb
I made the array const with `const char *deu_hilfe[] ={`..., 
Then i see a drop in the RAM Usage and a increase in ROM usage
when i compile my code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb `char const *const deu_hilfe[] = {` doesn`t work in my compiler, i get a error : `initalization image not found for deu_hilfe`

Comment: @patrick OK, there must be other details to your embedded system that would be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To move the arrays and strings into ROM, I would declare them as follows

```
const char * const deu_hilfe[] = {
    "START = Startet die Messung",
    "STOPP = Stoppt die Messung",
    "SETUP = Aufruf des Setups",
};

const char * const eng_hilfe[] = {
    "START = Start the measurement",
    "STOPP = Stop the measurment",
    "SETUP = Open the setup",
};
```

These declarations specify that the strings are `const`, and the array of pointers is also `const`.  You can then access the strings with code like this

```
const char * const *sprache_hilfe;

sprache_hilfe = eng_hilfe;
printf( "%s\n", sprache_hilfe[1] );
sprache_hilfe = deu_hilfe;
printf( "%s\n", sprache_hilfe[1] );
```

If that still doesn't work, then you'll have to look at the MAP output of the linker, to see where the linker decided to put the strings and the arrays. Then use the debugger to look at those memory addresses to verify that the strings and arrays were properly burned into the read-only memory.

Answer (score 0):

The actual characters of the string literals end up in flash anyway. Where you can save RAM is the two arrays, which occupy 24 bytes (2*3 pointers) in case of a 32-bit controller. So insert the `const` qualifiers like this. GCC has moved the arrays to the `.rodata` section after this.

```
char *const deu_hilfe[] = {
    "START = Startet die Messung",
    "STOPP = Stoppt die Messung",
    "SETUP = Aufruf des Setups",
};

char *const eng_hilfe[] = {
    "START = Start the measurement",
    "STOPP = Stop the measurment",
    "SETUP = Open the setup",
};
```

Your original code should work now, without any casting. You probably get 2 warnings from the compiler. GCC complains:

```
warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
```

To avoid that, you can either do a cast at assignment:

```
sprache_hilfe = (char**)eng_hilfe;
```

Or declare `sprache_hilfe` to point to const arrays only:

```
char *const *sprache_hilfe;
```

You original assignment

```
sprache_hilfe = (char*)eng_hilfe;
```

is wrong, as `eng_hilfe` points to char pointers, not chars.

Comment: This doesn`t work in my mirkoC AVR Compiler: `char *const deu_hilfe[] = {`  I get a error: **initalization image not found for deu_hilfe**